# Where does Netbeans 7 store FTP passwords

Tags: php, netbeans

I want to copy all my netbeans ftp details over to my friend's PC. I found th most of what i needed here:
`C:\Users\Jason Fonseca\.netbeans\7.0\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\php\project\RemoteConnections`

But I can't seem to find any passwords associated with that file.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably a question better posed through the NetBeans Support System - http://netbeans.org/kb/index.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
~\.netbeans\7.0\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\keyring\win32.properties
```

It will most likely be encrypted though.

**Edit:**

Looking at http://bits.nbextras.org/netbeans/trunk/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-keyring/org/netbeans/api/keyring/package-summary.html

It seems that the encryption is tied to your user account, so you wont be able to move that file to another computer.

Comment: For me, the fact it is encrypted is why I needed to know the location so I can add it to my sync ignore list. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can run wireshark or tcpdump to get the password really easily if it's FTP, this is what I did. This works if you've forgotten the password, just listen for it using tcpdump or wireshark as it connects and it will stream the FTP password in plain text. It saved me a HUGE headache trying to find the password somewhere.

Step by step instruction as per above:

1 Open Wireshark and select the active network interface

2 In the filter type ftp

[image]

PASS will display the password, marked red in picture. This does not work for SSH and it is recommended that you use SSH instead in future projects.

Comment: Hi David, welcome to SO! You should consider improving your answer by providing more details on how to use tcpdump or Wireshark for this effect. Keep it up!

Comment: Best response @David!

Answer (score 1):

This topic is quite old.. But, there are still some people (like me) that don't know everything about netbeans passwords, storing etc.
After some googling, I've found solution: use included import/export mechanism to export passwords and import them on another machine.

Open Netbeans, go to Tools->Options, there are 2 buttons on the bottom: export and import. Click export, select file for saving, check all or choosen settings. TIP: checking all doesn't check passwords and keyring by default, so you have to check it manually. After that your settings will be saved in zip file. Copy this file to other pc and then click import. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans cashes FTP, SFTP connetion information. Just replace "C:\netbeans install\bin\nb\var"

with old "var" folder.

Answer (score 1):

As the now two year old post above state, this five year old post is quite old, but never the less...

If you want to transfer your ftp connections & passwords you should try exporting them in a Netbeans configuration.

Open:

> (menus) Tools > Options > (button in lower left) Export
>   check "Keyring & Passwords" (second to last "Available Option") and any other options you want.

Note that when importing the config options in another installation; most items will overwrite any existing settings.  I'm not sure if items like macros, templates, keyboard shortcuts are additive -- as in, "If it's not already there, add it." or if it reset's all then changes everything to the imported settings.

Note: When importing, it will warn you just before it's too late that you should backup the existing configuration first; so you might want to do that on the second computer before proceeding.

On the target/other Netbeans installation, Open

> (menus) Tools > Options (button in lower left) Import then select the
>   configuration export file, check the options you want to import, then
>   click OK.

Note, I've never exported the keyring & passwords before.  I only export my templates, editor highlighting, and other tweaks.  I can't test it right now either because my v8.0.2 installation just decided to erase & refuse to remember all my ftp connection passwords. 8(

Hope this helps someone. 8)